# Asp validation summary not accessible for visually impaired people

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

In my web app there are several forms which are using `asp:ValidationSummary` and `asp:Label` for client and server side validation of the form. But when I use a screen reader (JAWS 16) for accessibility test on the page it just skips the error and visually impaired people will not hear any error read back also it is not detected if you just use keyboard to navigate the page.

So if anyone can tell me a way to focus on the validation summary as soon as the submit button is pressed if there is an error. That would be great, I am ok with a JavaScript solution too, but I can't really replace validation summary with any other type of validation as number of forms are more than 50.

**My Error Tag :**

```
      <div>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" tabindex="-1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="false"
           ShowSummary="true" ForeColor="" DisplayMode="List" CssClass="label label-danger"
          ValidationGroup="Registration" />

<asp:Label ID="LblError" runat="server" tabindex="-1" CssClass="label label-danger"></asp:Label>
      </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    function ValidateServerButtonClick() {
        if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
            Page_ClientValidate("Registration");
            if (Page_IsValid) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Submit Button**:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnContinue" CssClass="cui-btn disabled cui-btn-med cui-full-width" 
  runat="server" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btncontinue_Click"
  OnClientClick="ClearLabel()" Text="Sign up" Enabled="false" ValidationGroup="Registration" />
```

**Rendered HTML:**
[image]

**What I tried:**

I have already tried setting the focus intentionally on the error by calling `focus()` but that didn't worked either.

Comment: Setting the focus using JS to the validation summary should do the trick and JAWS will read that once focused. To be honest for me i always show the error messages in a dialog to make sure JAWS will read that.

Comment: Have you tried updating your JS function to set the focus to "ValidationSummary2" in case the page was not valid?

Comment: If I even use that `document.getElementById('<%=ValidationSummary2.ClientID %>').focus();` , after pressing submit it focuses to first missing field but not on the validation summary.

Comment: You can wrap that in a div and focus the div instead. I just noticed that you already have a div, just add an ID to that div and try setting the focus to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the focus to your container DIV should do it. JAWS should start reading the content once it's focused.

```
function ValidateServerButtonClick() {
            if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                Page_ClientValidate("Registration");
                if (Page_IsValid) {
                    return true;

                }
                else {
                    setTimeout(function () {
            $('#divid').focus();
        }, 700);
                    return false;

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too but it just not focus the validation summary, although if I click on the error generated then it starts to read it (or it gets focus).

Comment: Have you tried setting the focus on the container div?

Comment: Of course if you click on it JAWS will start reading. but blind folks can't click on that they have to tab into it.

Comment: Sorry for not adding what I already did in the question above, I have updated the question. setting focus on container div also didn't work. It just focuses on the first empty field.

Comment: That's allright. so you did try setting the focus to the div? and that also didn't work :/ if not can you post your rendered HTML? ummm is it an option to change your validation summary to show a message box instead?

Comment: No, we just updated our UI and took alerts out. :(. I really appreciate the way you are trying to help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94369/discussion-between-moe-and-suleman-mirza).

Comment: @SulemanMirza even if you have to change a bit the code in this answer to use it, you should not edit other people content and *change* what they mean.